# Capacitance calculator voltage

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, capacitance

There are couple parallel plate capacitance calculators on the internet but none of the ones I found had window where you input voltage, they dont even mention voltage anywhere.

For example this calculator says two charged parallel plates have 0.885 pico farad capacitance if their surface area is 100mm2 and distance is 1mm. It never mentions at what voltage this 0.885 pF is, I assume its 1 volt but I am not sure.

So the question is, what voltage does this calculator use to arrive at its result?
https://www.daycounter.com/Calculators/Plate-Capacitor-Calculator.phtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculator is giving you capacitance based on the physical characteristics of the capacitor, namely, plate area, separation, and electrical permittivity of the dielectric medium between the plates. Voltage is not required.

On the other hand, capacitance is also electrically defined as the charge on the capacitor per volt across the plates, or

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

hope this helps.